# SF story where man must answer questions to get to untold treasure

Tags: story-identification

There was a great SF story I read some time ago (probably 25+ years ago) where there was a well known treasure trove, guarded by a killer robot that would ask all comers a series of difficult questions from all areas (math, physics, literature, history, etc.)  But everyone eventually failed and died... until the last person managed to make it past the robot:

> By just answering gibberish to the robot.  Unfortunately, after collecting a ton of treasure, the robot casually asked him why he wanted it, he answered in a sensible way (something like "because it's valuable"), and the robot killed him, because he failed the final test.

Any ideas who wrote this?  What it was titled?

Comment: *"Blue. No, yell..."* --Galahad

Comment: A cyber sphinx? `:)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sounds like it could be ["The Sixth Palace"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6276470-the-sixth-palace) by [Robert Silverberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Silverberg). It seems to have appeared in a [number of anthologies](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52448).

> In a game strangely like "Who Wants to be a Millionaire" a robot asks questions of adventurers looking for treasure. If you answer all the questions correctly, you get the treasure, a vast trove of priceless artworks. But watch out! There are no lifelines in this version, and the penalty for a wrong answer literally is your life!

The story was originally published in *Galaxy*, February 1965 and you can [read it at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v23n03_1965-02/page/n99).

Comment: I had a feeling that this could be Robert Silverberg, but I had no idea why that popped into my head.  But as soon as you said the title/author I knew it was right.  Um...how on earth did you find this?

Comment: @Beska: The Google search that worked for me was "sci fi story treasure guarded by robot questions". The second link (the first one being for this question!) was to some [foreign language message board page](http://forum.prizma.si/viewtopic.php?t=692), which towards the bottom has an English summary of some of the stories from the anthology *Deep Space* (search "treasure" on the page). Then it was just a matter of searching around for the contents of that anthology, and *voilà*.

Comment: Thanks to [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162962/short-story-about-a-advanced-robot-guarding-a-treasure#comment431494_162962) on [a potential dupe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/162962/769), you can read it online [at archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v23n03_1965-02#page/n99/mode/2up)

Comment: I read this in the Needle In A Timestack anthology!

Comment: Thank you so much I've been wondering about this for years! Thing is, I remember hearing it on the radio, sometime in the 1970s. I wonder whether I'm imagining that.