# Old short story, possibly Ray Bradbury: alien computer/robot sets questions that you really shouldn't answer incorrectly

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ray-bradbury

I read a short story when I was a boy about some alien computer/robot that set questions that visiting people/aliens would try and answer, and possibly a terrible consequence if they answered incorrectly.

Sorry I can't be more precise, it was over 40 years ago!

Comment: do you recall if you read it in a compilation book, or a magazine, or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SF story where man must answer questions to get to untold treasure](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7617/sf-story-where-man-must-answer-questions-to-get-to-untold-treasure)

Comment: i honestly cant remember, but i will check the answers given thanks all.

Comment: I was going to answer that this sounds like Philip K. Dick's _[The Great C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_C)_, but it seems you are already sure that it is _The Sixth Palace_?

Comment: yes, it is the sixth palace thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There may be one than one story with this theme, but *[The Sixth Palace](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52448)* (1965) by Robert Silverberg fits the description.

> There was the treasure and there was the guardian of the treasure. And
> there were the whitening bones of those who had tried in vain to make
> the treasure their own.

The guardian asks challengers questions...

> It might demand the proofs of mathematical theorems. It might ask the
> translations of strange words. So they gathered, from their knowledge
> of what had befallen other men here. And, so it seemed, to give a
> wrong answer was to earn instant death.

Comment: And, if I recall correctly, answering correctly was equally fatal. The only way to appease the guardian was by responding with nonsense, which the protagonist did - right up until, having gained access to the treasure, he was asked why he was trying to do it, and carelessly replied with the truth. Oops.