# Short story about an advanced robot guarding a treasure

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

The story is about a technologically advanced robot that guards a treasure of great value.

To survive the encounter and be allowed to pass, one has to answer a number of questions.

Some guy attempts to cheat by using a search tech to find the answers as they are asked (Internet).

The guy answers all the questions until the end. The last question is less about search-able knowledge and more philosophical in nature. He fails to answer and is obliterated.

I remember it was in one of those Fantasy and Sci-fi pulp books. I used to buy them at used book stores when I was a kid.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE Sean! Feel free to take the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. Also, take a look at this [story-ID guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) to jog your memory and [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/162962/edit) any more details you might have missed out. Hope you stick around!

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/tQlB97u_d.webp?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=high

Comment: You can read "The Sixth Palace" at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/Galaxy_v23n03_1965-02#page/n99/mode/2up). Is that the story you were looking for?

Comment: I agree; it definitely was "The Sixth Palace." I was going to put that in as an answer, but I didn't know it had already been asked-and-answered in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the comments, and [SF story where man must answer questions to get to untold treasure](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7617/sf-story-where-man-must-answer-questions-to-get-to-untold-treasure?noredirect=1&lq=1), you're probably looking for [Robert Silverberg's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Silverberg) ["The Sixth Palace"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6276470-the-sixth-palace) [(ISFDB)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52448).

> In a game strangely like "Who Wants to be a Millionaire" a robot asks questions of adventurers looking for treasure. If you answer all the questions correctly, you get the treasure, a vast trove of priceless artworks. But watch out! There are no lifelines in this version, and the penalty for a wrong answer literally is your life!

The story was originally published in *Galaxy*, February 1965 and you can [read it at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v23n03_1965-02/page/n99).

Comment: I hate seeing comment answers and no posted answer, so plugging it in. :)

Comment: https://youtu.be/uio1J2PKzLI

Comment: I do apologize for not checking my answer...I reread this classic and enjoyed it very much. Thank you all!