# Trying to find a book with a probability puzzle in it

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a book where the characters encountered a vault(?) protected by a chain of 2 doors, one of which leads to death, the other one leads to the next chamber. There are a lot of these doors, and by the time the characters make it to the 4th, 5th, or 6th one, (I don't remember) they are told it's only the lobby, and not the vault itself.

I remember the puzzle being overcome by pure random choice. Either it was one of the characters randomly guessing, or letting their emotions pick for them, or something along those lines. The vault may have been owned by dwarves or gnomes, but I'm not sure about that detail. I do remember there being a person in the "lobby" chamber of the puzzle, though.

Comment: Sounds a bit like https://theneverendingstory.fandom.com/wiki/Sphinx_Gate

Comment: Is it any of the books listed on this tv tropes page?  https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DoorRoulette

Comment: @Judith Jones No, I don't believe it is any of those.

Comment: Was this a scene in a novel, or was it a short story?

Answer (score 2):

Chris Colfer's *[A Tale of Magic: A Tale of Sorcery](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/56620804-a-tale-of-sorcery)*.

[image: Front cover of A Tale of Sorcery]

> Brystal Evergreen is running out of time. It’s been almost a year since she made a deal with Death to find and destroy the Immortal in exchange for her life. But she still hasn’t found a single clue about who or where the Immortal is. To make matters worse, something dark and malignant has risen from deep within the earth, threatening life as we know it. To stop this new evil, the fairies and witches must work with all the kingdoms and territories, including the Righteous Brotherhood and their Army of the Dead. But is the threat more familiar than they expected? And why are a secretive group of Sorcerers convinced Xanthous Hayfield is connected to it?

They go through a vault where there are a series of multiple chambers, most of which kill you. They get really lucky and find out it is a lobby protecting the vault with the most powerful book of magic. There is a person in the vault that tells them the book was stolen a long time ago.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit like The Sixth Palace by Robert Silverberg.  There's a question about it [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7617/sf-story-where-man-must-answer-questions-to-get-to-untold-treasure).  Specifically, the treasure is guarded by a robot that asks questions and if you get the answers correct, you get the treasure, and if you answer incorrectly, you are killed.  The trick was that there are no correct answers, so the only way to win was to answer random non sequiturs.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exact, but this feels a bit like the [Sphinx Gate](https://theneverendingstory.fandom.com/wiki/Sphinx_Gate) from *The Neverending Story* by Michael Ende.

> When Atreyu sought out the Southern Oracle, he had to pass through three gates. The first gate, the Sphinx Gate, was a pair of yellow sphinxes that shoot lasers at anyone unworthy trying to pass between them. The second gate was a magic mirror that reveals one's true nature. The final gate was the No-Key Gate, which causes the person to lose their memory and can only be opened then.

....

> To get through the Sphinx Gate alive, you need to be a child - a boy/"brave warrior" (Atreyu) -, and you also need to have a kind, thoughtful, and courageous heart. This was how Atreyu got through the Sphinx Gate. He was kind and courageous at heart because he was trying to save Fantasia from The Nothing, a hungering void consuming the world, risking his life in the perilous journey.

Prior to entering, Atreyu meets the gnome Engywook, who has been studying the gates, and his wife Urgl. However, there are only three gates total.

As noted by Ifurini, a later challenge, the Temple of a Thousand Doors is more of a match for there being a large number of choices between two doors, although I think there are no consequences for the wrong choice, other than not getting where you want to go.

> “Yes,” said the lion. “But it’s not as simple as in other buildings. Only a genuine wish can lead you through the maze of the thousand doors. Without a genuine wish, you just have to wander around until you know what you really want. And that can take a long time.”

> It was a hexagonal room, rather like the enlarged cell of a honeycomb. Every second wall had a door in it, and on the intervening walls were painted strange pictures representing landscapes and creatures who seemed to be half plant and half animal. Bastian had entered through one of the doors

....

> The two doors leading out of a room always had something in common -— the shape, the material, the size, the color — but there was always some essential difference between them.

....

> As he went on and on, he began to wonder why this should be. His wish had sufficed to lead him into the maze, but apparently it was not definite enough to enable him to find the way out. He had wished for company. But now he realized that by company he had meant no one in particular. This vague wish hadn’t helped him at all. Thus far his decisions had been based on mere whim and involved very little thought. In every case he might just as well have taken the other door. At this rate he would never find his way out.

....

> Bastian turned around and saw that he had just stepped out of a little forest chapel. For that moment its door had been the way out of the Temple of a Thousand Doors. Bastian opened it again, but all he saw was the inside of a small chapel. The roof consisted only of a few rotted beams, and the walls were covered with moss.

Comment: Rather than the Sphinx Gate, I think the Temple of a Thousand Doors could fit the description: Bastian enters it in order to find Atreyu, and must traverse a sequence of doors, each one with two different-shaped doors. In order to reach his desired destination, Bastian must choose each time the door that has something in common with his target. I don't have the book close at hand now, so I don't remember if choosing a wrong door leads to dire consequences, other that not finding what he was looking for.

Comment: So noted. I've added some small amount of quotes from the copy of the book on the Internet Archive (which unfortunately is not available to borrow, just to search through).

Comment: I played a bit with the Internet Archive book search function to look for meaningful quotes. The general shape of the rooms: _"It was a hexagonal room, rather like the enlarged cell of a honeycomb. Every second wall had a door in it, and on the intervening walls were painted strange pictures representing landscapes and creatures who seemed to be half plant and half animal. Bastian had entered through one of the doors"_.

Comment: _"The two doors leading out of a room always had something in common -— the shape, the material, the size, the color — but there was always some essential difference between them."_